# Laravel scope doesn't work

Tags: laravel

Migration `class CreatePostsTable extends Migration`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('number')->nullable();
        $table->text('text');
        $table->boolean('is_approved')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

model `Post`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        'number'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['published_at', 'deleted_at'];

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date) 
    {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::now('Europe/Moscow');
    }

    public function scopeApproved($query) 
    {
        $query->where('is_approved', '==', '1');
    }
}
```

Controller `HomeController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Post;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $posts = Post::latest('published_at')->approved()->paginate(20);
        return view('home.index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

So it is expected that on the Home page I receive only `approved` posts but instead all posts are shown on the page. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope uses the `==` operator, which is great for php, but since the operator will be used in the query you need just a regular equal sign:

```
$query->where('is_approved', '=', '1');
```

Or just

```
$query->where('is_approved', 1);
```

Comment: Well, in previous versions of Laravel `$query->where('is_approved', '==', '1');` worked just fine, I didn't know it changed. Thanks a lot for the help, `$query->where('is_approved', 1);` works!